# Getting wp_timezone undefined within a namespace

Tags: timezones, namespace

My workaround at the moment, within a shortcode, is to just copy the WP native code to get the Timezone within my (namespaced) class:

```
new \DateTimeZone( $this->wp_timezone_string() ));
private function wp_timezone_string() {
    $timezone_string = get_option( 'timezone_string' );

    if ( $timezone_string ) {
        return $timezone_string;
    }

    $offset  = (float) get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
    $hours   = (int) $offset;
    $minutes = ( $offset - $hours );

    $sign      = ( $offset < 0 ) ? '-' : '+';
    $abs_hour  = abs( $hours );
    $abs_mins  = abs( $minutes * 60 );
    $tz_offset = sprintf( '%s%02d:%02d', $sign, $abs_hour, $abs_mins );

    return $tz_offset;
}
```

But I'm wondering why I can't just call make a call to `\wp_timezone()` (escaped for namespace).

Is it because the file that contains that class hasn't loaded yet?

Comment: Where/when are you trying to use it? Is this inside a theme?

Comment: No it's within a plugin, called by a shortcode.

Comment: and you're using the latest WordPress?

Comment: There's the rub! I was developing in v5.2 and these functions are since v5.3.

Comment: Awesome, can you post it as an answer rather than a comment so I can upvote?

Comment: Sure. My pleasure. Will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Tom J Nowell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) for the insightful comment above.

Turns out that [wp_timezone](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone/) is a *relatively* recent addition to Wordpress, and didn't exist in the version of WP I was developing in. It was added, as the Changelog says, in `v5.3`. I was using `v5.2`.

The function itself:

```
function wp_timezone() {
    return new DateTimeZone( wp_timezone_string() );
}
```

Simpy wraps the result of `wp_timezone_string` in a native php `DateTimeZone` object. The `wp_timezone_string` was also added in `v5.3`.

Since this is a brand new plugin, I'm not going to support older version of Wordpress. For pragmatic reasons, and in solidarity with the movement to encourage users to upgrade WP environments, I have also opted to not support versions of php (like `v5.6`) that are past their End of Life.